# She's not talking about her children, but about the customers of a subsidiary of pharmaceutical company Whitehall-Robins~

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> She's not talking about her children, but about the customers of a subsidiary **of** pharmaceutical company Whitehall-Robins, where she works as supervisor of credit and collections.

Whitehall-Ronbins is a subsidiary? or
a subsidiary belongs to Whitehall-Robins (**of** is a possessive case if a subsidiary belongs to W-Rs)?

I think W-Rs has a subsidiary.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your analysis.  "Of" indicates a possessive. So the subsidiary belongs to W-Rs.

Whitehall-Robins is a company that makes medicines.  A subsidiary is a company that is owned by another company. For example "Jaguar cars" is a subsidiary of "Tata motors".